# Within a batch file how can I make this only create junctions when it doesn't already exist without error

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

```
@for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%g in %folderList% do mklink /j  "%goingtoPath%\%%h" "%originalPath%\%%g"
```

I have tried adding an if not exist in front of the do mklink

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [tour]. Also, please read [ask] a good question. It would also help us help you if you provided a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: Regardless of my comment above and seeing some errors in your code, if you do not want to see the error you could easily redirect STDERROR to the NUL device: `mklink /j  "%goingtoPath%\%%h" "%originalPath%\%%g" 2>NUL`.  To check for existence use the `IF` command with the `NOT` and `EXIST` option. `IF NOT EXIST "C:\some path\some folder" mklink ......`

Comment: Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to learn the correct syntax for the `FOR /F` command. You should also post a [mcve] of your code, we need to see exactly how the variable `%folderlist%` is created, and a real world example of its data, in order to provide focused advice. Please ensure that you've taken the [tour], and read through all of the pages of [ask], to understand how this process is supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you Squashman.  the 2>NUL works to ignore the error. I will try to get the IF Not to work to learn from it too.  I will also read up on the links provided so I can better ask my question and show more of an example to help with the trouble shooting.